# Quantitative methods book in R

Tags: references

I'm studying this book: [Statistics: Unlocking the Power of Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119163668) to introduce me the basic statistics (quantitative methods).

Throughout the book they use the software Statkey to do the simulations (the sampling distributions, randomization distributions, bootstrap distributions, hypothesis tests, etc ), we can access the first half of the book in the link.

I need a book which covers the same contents but with the simulations in R programming, are there some out there?